# Am using datepicker unable to select next year date what is going wrong?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
$(document).on('focus',".expdate",function(){
$('.expdate').datepicker({minDate:0});
$(this).datepicker();
$( ".expdate" ).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat' , 'dd/mm/yy');
```

Even i tried with changeYear: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('focus','.expdate',function(){
   $('.expdate').datepicker({ minDate:0, dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'});
});
```